# Preciso juntar dados de duas tabelas sql numa requisição no nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, express.js, sequelize-js

Tenho um código backend em node js e um banco de dados com nomes de usuários e imagens deles, sendo um relacionamento **de um (usuário) pra muitos (várias imagens)**, e preciso juntar essas informações em um json para mandar pro meu aplicativo em react-native. Estou utilizando o sequelize para fazer as tabelas e realizar as consultas.

A tabela de usuário possui id, nome e descricao e a tabela de imagens possui um id, nome da imagem e uma chave estrangeira para pegar o id do usuário que ela pertence (idUsuário)

Mas eu não sei como fazer essa junção e parece que um join duplicaria os dados do usuário caso ele tivesse mais de duas imagens, como posso fazer sem se repetir?

A ideia seria receber **um json via requisição get** mais ou menos assim:

```
  [
    {nome:"Eduardo", imagens:[
      {url:"algo.jpg"},
      {url:"imagem.jpg"},
    ]},
    {nome:"Pretinho"}, imagens:[
      {url:"algo.jpg"},
      {url:"imagem.jpg"},
      {url: "foto.jpg"},
    ]},
    {nome:"Pintado"}, imagens:[
      {url:"algo.jpg"},
    ]},
  ]
```

Aqui estão os códigos do sequelize para as tabelas

[A tabela de usuários, coloquei como nome de cão só para mudar na minha prática](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZjmq.png)

[A tabela de fotos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsZRS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri uma forma de fazer isso com estruturas de repetição, segue a solução abaixo (fiz de uma forma mais ilustrativa, os dados podem ser mais complexos no problema real, mas a solução é a mesma):

```
var cães = [{
    nome: "Cachorro"
},
{
    nome: "Tigre"
}]

var imagens = [{
    uri: "oainor",
    nome: "Cachorro",
},
{
    uri: "betopnie",
    nome: "Tigre",
},{
    uri: "ipnbttb",
    nome: "Tigre",
},{
    uri: "epibnt",
    nome: "Tigre",
}]

var imgs = []

var caoAndImgs = []

for (let i = 0; i < cães.length; i = i + 1 ){
    for (let y = 0; y < imagens.length; y = y + 1 ){
      if (cães[i].nome === imagens[y].nome){
          let img = imagens[y].uri
          imgs.push(img)
          
          console.log(imgs)          
      } 
    }
    
  caoAndImgs.push({...cães[i], imagens: imgs})

  console.log(caoAndImgs)
  
  imgs = []
}
```

[O retorno será essa aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfjv2.png)

No back-end, se alguém tiver o mesmo problema, é só trocar a propriedade das imagens pela chave estrangeira das imagens